# How to sample by factor level, instead of row indices in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

How can I sample over a data frame instead of over row indices?

Specifically, I am not sure how to change the `indices` argument in the `bs` function to select multiple rows that make up a factor level, instead of only selecting individual row indices. For context, I am using the the function `bs` in conjunction with the `boot` function from the `boot` package to bootstrap confidence intervals.

The function `bs` allows `boot` function to sample over the data frame using the `indices` argument.

```
bs <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot function to select sample 
  shares <- aggregate(d$PASVINT3W, by=list(d$Prod), FUN = sum)
  shares <- shares[1:4 , ]
  names(shares) <- c("Prod", "sum.prob")
  shares <- shares$sum.prob/sum(shares$sum.prob)
  return(shares) 
}
```

**Then `boot` actual does the sampling.**

As a simplified example, I have variable `type1`, where every two rows are grouped, i.e. 1,1,2,2,3,3. I would like to sample over these groupings, instead over individual rows.

```
     device geslacht leeftijd type1
1       mob        0       53     1     
2       tab        1       64     1     
3        pc        1       50     2     
4       tab        0       75     2     
5       mob        1       54     3     
6        pc        1       58     3     
7        pc        1       57     4     
8        pc        0       68     4     
9        pc        0       66     5     
10      mob        0       45     5     
11      tab        1       77     6     
12      mob        1       16     6
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option would be

```
lst <- split(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$type1)
df1[unlist(lst[sample(names(lst))]),]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   distinct(type1) %>%
   mutate(type1 = sample(type1)) %>%
   right_join(df1, .)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'm still a bit unsure as to how to synthesize the base r answer with the the `indices` argument in the `bs` function. I guess an important part I didn't make clear is that the 'boot' function actually handles the sampling, but I am not sure how to change the `indices` argument to allow `boot` to sample over the factor level instead of individual row indices.

Comment: @RTrain3k Wouldn't the `unlist(lst[...` would be the indices

Comment: OK I see what you mean. If the subsequent function `boot` does the actual sampling. Wouldn't I need to exclude `[sample(names(lst))]` and only include `df1[unlist(lst),]?

Comment: When I tried what I mentioned above and run the `boot` function I get the error ` Error in split.default(seq_len(nrow(data)), data$type1) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0`